# Como rellenar ClaseVO con objeto que devuelve el api enviando token en header

Tags: java, api, rest

Estoy consumiendo un api con spring boot uso RestTemplate normalmente lo hago de esta manera.

```
vousuario = rest.getForObject(urlusuarios + "/login/" + correo + "/" + clave, CUsuarioVO.class);
            System.out.print("El resultado es: " + vousuario.getUsnombres());
```

Esta ves necesito lo mismo pero enviando un token ya logre enviar el token y obtener el resultado en un response String pero necesito recibirlo es en Un Objeto clase con sus set y get

Asi sirve bien:

```
public static HttpEntity<String> getHttpEntity() {
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(getHeaders());
        return entity;
    }

    private static HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        headers.set("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        headers.set("Authorization", token);
        return headers;
    }

    public static void getUsuario() {
        try {

            HttpEntity<String> entity = getHttpEntity();
            response = rest.exchange(URL_USUARIOS + "/consultar/3", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

            CUsuarioVO usvo = rest.postForObject(URL_USUARIOS, entity, CUsuarioVO.class);
            
            if (response.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
                System.out.println("RESPONSE: " + response.getBody());
            } else {
                System.out.println("SIN RESPONSE");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("el error: " + e);
        }
    }
```

Pero cuando lo hago de esta manera me subraya en error y necesito de esta es para llenar los setter con los resultados ya que el anterior es una cadena

```
CUsuarioVO usvo = rest.getForObject(URL_USUARIOS, entity, CUsuarioVO.class);
// El error lo marca en = getForObject solo me deja usar postForObject y la solicitud debe ser get
// Error: The method getForObject(String, Class<T>, Object...) in the type RestTemplate is not applicable // for the arguments (String, HttpEntity<String>, Class<CUsuarioVO>)


// === segunda forma 

ResponseEntity<CUsuarioVO> vo = rest.exchange(URL_USUARIOS + "/consultar/3", HttpMethod.GET, entity, CUsuarioVO.class);
            
System.out.print("nombres: "+ vo // Aca no deja obtener los get

// ==== Tercera forma
ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> vo = rest.exchange(URL_USUARIOS + "/consultar/3", HttpMethod.GET, entity, Map.class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De la siguiente manera lo puedes hacer yo lo echo así y funciona bien.
Espero te sirva.

```
// == En el entity pasas el header y la clase de tu objeto a recibir
            HttpEntity<CUsuarioVO> entity = new HttpEntity<CUsuarioVO>(getHeaders());
            // ==== Recibes el response 
            ResponseEntity<CUsuarioVO> response = rest.exchange(URL_USUARIOS + "/consultar/3", HttpMethod.GET, entity,
                    CUsuarioVO.class);
            CUsuarioVO usuario = response.getBody(); // EL response lo pasas a tu objeto
System.out.print("NOMBRES: " + usuario.getNombredelmetodo); // Imprimes el valor que tienen los getter
```